# Put box around set of axeses

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a simple way to draw a box around a set of axes...es (yea axeses --- blame matplotlib's silly terminology). Ideally I would like to easily acces the lower right and upper right corner coordinates of all axes and find the respective minimum and maximum and then use these two coordiantes as the lower left and upper right coordiantes of a rectangle patch. But the API does not provide these functions, as far as I can tell.

Can you think of a simple and reusable way to do this?

Here is a picture of what I am right now. The box does not evenly frame the two axes:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
from matplotlib import patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.1, -1:1:.1]
Z = X+Y

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax1.contourf(X, Y, Z)
ax2.contourf(X, Y, -Z)

frame = patches.Rectangle(
        (-.1,-.1), 1.2, 3.2, transform=ax2.transAxes, fill=True, zorder=0
    )
fig.patches.append(frame)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you be bit more specific about what you want to achieve. Maybe a full MCVE with what you get and what should be different? From you picture it is not really clear.

Comment: Ok, added an MCVE and a better picture. I want an easy non-fiddling-around way to frame these two axeses.